# HTTPS site : Failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: parsing, extjs, https, fonts

Recently I migrated my (Extjs) WebSite from HTTP to HTTPS.
The ExtJs site is owned into an IIS (Web) container.

But now I've errors into the Chrome console, because none of fonts is correctly downloaded.
All works fine before when the site was on HTTP mode.

Should I change the call to the font in my css file ?
Or should have a specific clause into the web.config for font files ?

Error :

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: https://.../resources/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Failed to decode downloaded font: https://.../resources/fonts/entypo-font/font/entypo.woff
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

...
```

Extract of CSS file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url('../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: If you're using the network anyway, why are you serving your own copy instead of just using google's CDN (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans), reducing your own load, and allowing browsers to rely on cache more?

Comment: because some of our clients use the application on their internal network without Internet access.

Comment: in that case the first step is to grab fresh copies of OpenSans, and verify that they pass [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) and [OTS](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots) validation (your error message is OTS rejecting the fonts, probably because either *something* is corrupting their bytes, or they are already corrupt)

Comment: With fresh copies and a new rebuild, It's works now. Thanks Mike.